# JFrog Container Registry (JCR) won't load

Tags: docker, artifactory, jfrog-container-registry

Environment:

- Macbook Pro: 10.13.6 (17G65) High Sierra
- Docker Desktop: 2.4.0.0
- Docker Engine: 19.03.13
- Browser: Chrome Version 87.0.4280.88 (Official Build) (x86_64)

I can't get the JFrog Container Registry webapp to run.
I followed the instructions on their website [here](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JCR6X/Installing+with+Docker) to run a local docker container. When I initially connect to `http://127.0.0.1:8081/artifactory`, I see a loading animation like this:

[image]

Then, it automatically redirects to `http://127.0.0.1:8082/ui` and gives an error:

> "This site can’t be reached. 127.0.0.1 refused to connect."

[image]

If I try to go to `http://127.0.0.1:8081/artifactory`, it just goes back to `http://127.0.0.1:8082/ui` and fails again. I tried to use incognito and other browsers with the same result

I tried several `docker run` variants, but the simplest one I tried was:

```
$docker run --name JCR -d -p 8081:8081 -v /Users/username/git/artifactory/docker-registry:/var/opt/jfrog/artifactory  docker.bintray.io/jfrog/artifactory-jcr:latest
```

I checked the docker container and it is running and listening on various ports:

```
$ netstat -tulpn | grep LISTEN
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8091          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      3693/java
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8070          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      3562/node
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8040          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      3693/java
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8045            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      3693/java
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8046          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      3274/jf-router
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8047          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      3274/jf-router
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8015          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      3693/java
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8049          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      3274/jf-router
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8081            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      3693/java
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8086          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      3422/jf-metadata
tcp6       0      0 :::8082                 :::*                    LISTEN      3274/jf-router
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you followed the instructions for 6.x, which are not valid for 'latest', which is 7.x. You should follow the instructions for Docker for 7.x (https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Installing+Artifactory#InstallingArtifactory-DockerInstallation). The only difference is that you will need to change it from pointing to the PRO to JCR.

If you want a super quick and dirty way to just get it up and running, this will do:

```
docker volume create artifactory-data
docker pull releases-docker.jfrog.io/jfrog/artifactory-jcr:latest
docker run -d --name artifactory -p 8082:8082 -p 8081:8081 -v artifactory-data:/var/opt/jfrog/artifactory releases-docker.jfrog.io/jfrog/artifactory-jcr:latest
```

You will then access it at localhost:8082 (or localhost:8081, which will just redirect to 8082).

Comment: Well their instructions pointed to that JCR docker image and that's what I used.

Nothing on either confluence page nor in docker image name indicates the version (6.x vs 7.x)

I noticed that your example also uses the latest jcr but from a different URL (releases-docker vs docker.bintray.io)

I tried the new URL and this works now. I will mark this as answered. Thanks!

Comment: I am using host directories to persist data. However, When I remove and recreate the docker container, all my data is gone. Moreover, the hosted directory doesn't contain anything. Using Docker Named Volumes is not an option unfortunately. Is there a reason why that's not working? Docker syntax included in updated post.

Comment: I tried the command you updated and it works fine after deletion and recreation of the container. My guess would be that your docker daemon is not able to write to the location you are mounting. I would check the JCR logs, it may print out an error about this.

Comment: So when you run my updated command, you actually have data populate in the host side (equivalent of `/Users/username/git/artifactory/docker-registry`)? OK. I'll look at the logs.